# How to resign .xcarchive in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have `.xcarchive` built by another developer. I want to resign the `.xcarchive` to generate the `.ipa` in Xcode with my own certificate.

What do I need from another developer who created the original `.xcarchive`? How can I resign the `.xcarchive`?

Answer (score 0):

You typically sign the .ipa file which is located inside the .xcarchive under Products/Applications.